# structure member update using cffi python

Tags: python, struct, cffi

Hi all I have a structure with the following members

```
struct test {       
    uint8_t         one;      
    uint32_t        two;      
    uint8_t         three;     
    bool_t          four;   
    bool_t          five;  
    bool_t          six;                                         
    bool_t          seven;

};
```

I have following python function

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi=FFI()
dll = ffi.dlopen( 'test.dll')
def test_one(**kwargs ):
        p_val = ffi.new( 'struct test*' ) #create a struct using cffi
        dout = dll.test_one( p_val ) #call the func from dll
        kwargs['one'] =str( p_val.one) 
        kwargs['two '] = str( p_val.two )
        kwargs['three'] =str( p_val.three) 
        kwargs['four'] = str( p_val.four)
        kwargs['five'] = str( p_val.five)
        kwargs['six'] =str( p_val.six) 
        kwargs['seven'] = str( p_val.seven)
        print kwargs
```

when I print the struct members i.e. kwargs then the struct members are not updated except for the first member. Am I passing or receiving any wrong values?
Please let me know any mistakes in my code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the problem bool_t in python takes 1 byte but for some strange reason bool_t in dll which was created by using visual studio c++ (version 4) takes 4 bytes due to this only few elements of structure are updated (by luck). Resolved the problem by #define bool_t char.